# decode proposer pub key format to get its address

Tags: go-ethereum, cryptography, ecdsa

I want to get the address of the following public key for a proposer provided by the beacon node:

`0x8f97b04a965ffe46247ae428892e09499511e94f6dee5366e710eab937b42bfec3861466e6575a69b39c5d23e0282bcf`

Following https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/signature_test.go a public key either has a length of 128 or 66 in compressed format. What format is the provided key and how can i decode it to get its address?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure I understand the question. You've provided a public key which is an address used in the consensus layer. You can explore information about this validator [here](https://beaconcha.in/validator/8f97b04a965ffe46247ae428892e09499511e94f6dee5366e710eab937b42bfec3861466e6575a69b39c5d23e0282bcf).

Checking the link, you can see that the public key used to make the deposit is `0xf82ac5937a20dc862f9bc0668779031e06000f17`. This address triggered a Lido smart contract to make several deposits.